# HTML not rendering in APEX

Tags: html, oracle-apex

I am running apex 20.2.
I am trying to add some html to the heading section in a column.
The issue is it isnt working or not rendering when I refresh the page. Is there another way?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the same environment as yours (Apex 20.2, interactive report's heading for a *plain text* column) - works as expected:

[image]

Comment: hmm ok strange thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it’s not working because you need to fill “**alternative label** “ ;

For example; your **heading** label is “ Completed `<span> something </span>`”

and your **alternative label** is “Completed”

So you need to *choice the type for the one that you can use “alternative label”* (p.s; even the type POP-up LOV has it).

(There can be other solutions but if you still have this problem even everything look correct ,try  the one I suggested)